# How to load old (1 month ago) messages from Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

### Desktop:

[image]

*(at some point "load more" button disappears)*

### Mobile App:

[image]

*(pull down, infinite scroll, more messages won't load)*

---

I opened Chrome Developer Tools to see what web requests are sent when I click "load more" button:

[image]

Sidenote: reputational risk and lost trust - I am a regular user - I wasn't abusing any functionality. If I was to send 1000 messages a day to all my contact book - I would understand that loading old messages is not working.

I'm actually really frustrated that such a basic functionality is not working.

Maybe I should report this case to FB security as my account is being hacked?

Comment: Do you know how to download all your information from FB? If so, do that first. Second, check which applications you've authorized to post to your FB wall and deauthorize as needed. It's probably that, not hacking.

Comment: Good question. This is a common problem.

Answer (score 1):

Accept new Terms & Conditions on WhatsApp.

Now I can access my old messages on Facebook.

**EDIT 20 Nov 2016:** It was working for a moment. As of Today I can scroll to 4 Sep 2016. Not cool :(